How it is expected to make domain-joined linux computers connect Wi-Fi 802.1x with computer authentication?
I have an Active Directory domain with Windows computers: when I join computer to AD, it gets computer account (computername$) and 802.1x group policy which says

Connect to SSID mySSID 
validate AAA server issuer certificate and it's FQDN, 
use PEAP\MSCHAPv2, 
use computer account for authentication

Works good.
How can I configure Ubuntu Linux Desktop computer, joined with sssd to same AD Domain, to authenticate to Wi-Fi same way?
